# What does the "save this question" button do

Tags: support

What does the "save this question" button do?
How do I find it and recall it after I have saved it?

Comment: The wording of the other question is... suboptimal... but the answer is what I would write for this question too.

Comment: [**Bookmarks have evolved into Saves**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-have-evolved-into-saves) and [How do I find my list of “Save this answer” bookmarks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/385733/how-do-i-find-my-list-of-save-this-answer-bookmarks)